# Set default properties to visual component

Tags: android

I have several components in my form. I would like all components to have font color set to white as default

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="179dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="178dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="236dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to set all further components to be set to white without using line  `android:textColor="#ffffff"` ? Is it possible to set font color somewhere in top level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Themes`. Themes are used to style every view of the app at once.

Create a `themes.xml` file inside your `/res/values` folder, if it doesn't exist already.

Inside it define your theme and define the styling properties you want to apply to all views.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.Example" 
        parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apply this theme to your complete app by defining in `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside `application` tag.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example">
```

Sample Output:

[image: Default theme sample output]